# Realistically writing culture shock for this character?

Tags: character-development, setting

I want some help writing a character.

Her name is Christina and she lived in an underground bunker, in a post-apocalyptic world, so she’s really sheltered. But she has to leave, along with a group of more experienced Wastelanders, and has to adapt to the surface.

In this world the bunker dwellers basically live in strict totalitarian-esque place, where the population are made to follow strict rules, upkeeping their shelter and society. The surface by contrast, is the opposite for the most part. Nomadic scavengers and raiders, with scattered farming settlements and more primitive tribal societies.

How do I realistically write the culture shock that Christina experiences on the surface?

Comment: Could you maybe provide more on her own "culture" so we can go on about thinking what can shock such a character the most?
For example lets assume they view sex as means to an end and have a strict no sex for fun policy. 
She goes to Gomorrah and she is shocked to see the there is something called prostitution. 
Also with good stuff. They all read, write, even play an instrument. 
Outside well. People are idiots 
So please provide more on the culture of the bunker

Comment: This is a question better suited for Writing.SE, not Worldbuilding.SE

Comment: @Halfthawed's right, questions about how-to-write belong on [writing.se]. Remember, worldbuilding (on-topic) is about developing and consistently using the rules of a fictional world wherein an infinite number of stories can be told. Storybuilding (off-topic) is about circumstances, plot, and character choices/actions. My understanding is that early-on the idea was floated to create a "storybuilding.SE" site, but no-one could figure out how to make it work under SE's rules (I doubt it could be done today, but the sites are getting more flexible).

Comment: Also...have you watched "the100"? Totalitarian underground bunker & totalitarian space station societies vs nomadic scavengers/raiders? Check!

Comment: The first thing about her shock is that she's probably suffering from agoraphobia and doesn't realize it until she sees the sky the first time.

Comment: @Sciborg: I asked this on Worldbuilding.Stack Exchange bit it got migrated. Also, I barely got any answers on that question.

Comment: @DTCooper That's fair, however this is an exact duplicate of your previous question, and that is generally against rules so I voted to close the most recent copy. I apologize that Writing SE is a bit inactive as of late, I wish your question had gotten more answers the first time around because it is a very good question.

Comment: @Sciborg: Is there anyway I could get my question more answers?

Comment: @DTCooper Wait a bit longer and maybe you will get some more :) again this site is more inactive than it used to be and sometimes you just have to wait a bit for discussion to happen.

Comment: @Sciborg: Wait, I could bounty it could bounty it couldn’t I?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111781/discussion-between-sciborg-and-dt-cooper).

Answer (score 0):

If there are a group of them they probably won't suffer from culture shock, unless they're living as part of a larger community.

Sounds more like they will be camping in a wilderness, which obviously will have challenges , but they will bring their culture, language, assumptions and prejudices with them.

Comment: No, it’s one character living with a group of experienced wastelanders.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can be kind of like the film *Blast to the Past* and Brendan Fraser when he comes out of his bunker and he experiences culture shock. They made it comical but your story can have a different arc and you can make it whatever you want it to be. Great concept!